# Automatic scrolling a text view after appending text in Android

Tags: java, android, textview, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to make the content of a textview to automatically scroll to the bottom at the most recent text appended. I tried many ways from many post but seems there's no way to make it work. I trie also different layout_wheight and width parameters and so on. The silly thing is that I already made it in the past and it worked, but now using the same set up it is not.
Here's my latest xml code:

```
    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/askScv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/askTxv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:maxLines="99999"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/answerScv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answerTxv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:maxLines="99999"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </ScrollView>
</TableRow>
```

and the Java one:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mQuestionEdt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.questionEdt);

    mAnswerTxv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTxv);
    mAnswerTxv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    mAnswerScv=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.answerScv);
    mAnswerScv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

    mAskTxv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.askTxv);
    mAskTxv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    mAskScv=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.askScv);
    mAskScv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

    mAskBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.askBtn);
    mAskBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    mStartBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    mStartBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Bundle result;

    if (view.equals(mAskBtn)) {
        result=mAnsweringMachine.answer(mQuestionEdt.getText().toString());
        mAskTxv.append("\n" + mQuestionEdt.getText().toString());
        mAskScv.smoothScrollTo(0,mAskTxv.getBottom());
        mAnswerTxv.append("\n" + result.getString(AnsweringMachine.DIALOGUE_RESULT));
        mAnswerScv.smoothScrollTo(0,mAnswerTxv.getBottom());
    } else if (view.equals(mStartBtn)) {

        result = mAnsweringMachine.runStartingPrompt();
        mAnswerTxv.append(result.getString(AnsweringMachine.DIALOGUE_RESULT));
        //mAnswerScv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }

}
```

And here's my old working code, xml:

```
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/terminalScv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/terminalTxv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</ScrollView>
```

and Java one:

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_terminal);
    terminalTxv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.terminalTxv);
    terminalScv=(ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.terminalScv);
    terminalScv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
}

@Override
protected void onBtDataReceived(int[] data) {
    super.onBtDataReceived(data);
    String out=String.valueOf(terminalTxv.getLineCount())+" - ";
    for (int x=0;x<data.length-1;x++){
        out+=data[x];
        out+=" ";
    }
    out+="\n";
    terminalTxv.append(out);
    terminalScv.smoothScrollTo(0, terminalTxv.getBottom());
}
```

Hope somebody can make me understand this enigma....
Thanks!

Comment: any help about this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the XML for the textView element I would try to add:

android:gravity="bottom"

Also are you sure you need to specify android:scrollbars="vertical" in both scrollview and textview? In addition, I noticed the difference between old working version is that it doesn't uses setMovementMethod() - personally I would use this method without scrollview, but since you already have scroollview I don't see a reason why would you need it...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I will try on this week end and let you know